# Ea cricket 2007 "game.exe has stopped working "

Tags: gaming

When I click on the EA Cricket 2007 icon this error show up on screen

> game.exe has stopped working

I have tried solutions which are given on different websites but this didn't fix.

Comment: This isn't really a StackOverflow question, however it may be appropriate for SuperUser or gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, on any SE site please use proper capitalization, spelling, and formatting (I fixed it for you though). You should list the specific solutions you tried and their results. There's not enough information in your question to answer the question, even if it were on-topic.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to try other solutions, then.  There's no way for us to know which those are.